# Show that a holomorphic function converges uniformly on a closed disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D(0,1)$ s.t $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$.

I want to show that $$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} f(z^n)$$

converges uniformly on $\overline{D(o,r)}$ with $0 < r < 1$.

I really don't know how to go about

**attempt at soulution**:

Thanks to the Schwarz Lemma, we have $|f(z)| \leq |z|$

So for $|z| < r$ we have $|z^n| < |r^n|$

Therefore, $\Sigma_{n=0} ^{\infty} |f(z^n)| ≤ \Sigma_{n=0} ^{\infty}  |z^n| ≤ \Sigma_{n=0} ^{\infty} |r^n| < \infty $

By Weierstrass's M-test, $\Sigma_{n=0} ^{\infty} f(z^n)$ converges uniformly.

is that the right way to approach the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should read

"......converges uniformly on $\overline{D(o,r)}$ with $0 \leq r < 1"$

($r<1$ !). (observe that $f$ is not defined for $|z|=1$)

The Schwarz - Lemma gives $|f(z)| \le |z|$ for all $z$ with $|z|<1$. Thus, for $|z| \le r<1$ we get $|z^n| \le r^n$.

Now its your turn.

Comment: Yes thanks, I edited my post

Comment: Hi Rambo, can you now show what you want to show ?

Comment: I am trying, I'll keep you updated, thanks though

Comment: Here, I edited my post and showed my attempt